# Laraval handling file retrieved from another Laraval api

Tags: php, laravel, curl, file-handling

I have 2 Laravel APIs.
One API requesting a file from the second with a curl.
I want to get the file as an UploadedFile without calling to new UploadedFile().
Or as alternative I want to create UploadedFile with the response contant without saving it as a temp file (and then calling new UploadedFile() with a temp path).

First API for requesting the file:

```
    $url = 'http://someurl.org';

    $CR = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($CR, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($CR, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
    curl_setopt($CR, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($CR, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    $response = curl_exec($CR);
    

    curl_close($CR);
    return $response;
```

[Response print screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RY6mo.png)

Second API:

```
public function getFile(string $fileId)
{
    $recordedFile = RecordedFile::where('file_id', $fileId)->first();
    if (!$recordedFile) {
        return response(['message' => 'file not found'], 400);
    }
    $headers = [
        'Content-type' => Storage::mimeType($recordedFile->path),
        'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment; filename=' . $recordedFile->original_name .''
    ];

    $file = Storage::get($recordedFile->path);
    return response($file, 200, $headers);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found this.
https://gist.github.com/waska14/f3be9c1cf0731a85753c9f34e9fca348

The FileHelper::fromBase64($this->input('file')) part helped me.